# Reinitiate Flip.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using the jquery plugin jquery flip https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/ to create a card flipping system in my web page.  The documentation specifies a way to unregister the flip event from the element, which I have working successfully.  I want to re-register the flip capability when a button is clicked, however.  When I inspect the element the .flip class is applied, but the on-hover event doesn't work to flip the card anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code `$("#card").off(".flip");` only unregister the events, but does not clear the library's settings on the element.

To register the events you need to re-initialize the element again, and here is the problem, there is no info on the documentation on how to do that (as you said).

But if you read the libary's code you will see that you can do that by clearing the `flip-model` data and trick the library to re-initialize the element.

```
// Unregister flip
$("#card").off(".flip");

// Register flip again
$("#card").data("flip-model", false);
$("#card").flip({ ... }); // Insert your options
```

If you want the element to keep the old options on register, you can save them before clearing them

```
// Unregister flip
$("#card").off(".flip");

// Register flip with old settings
var options = $("#card").data("flip-model").setting;
$("#card").data("flip-model", false);
$("#card").flip(options);
```

---

**PS**: Removing the data using `$("#card").removeData("flip-model");` produces visual bugs while `$("#card").data("flip-model", false);` works with no problems.